Climate and ecosystems of Zealandia
As per the title, I have not been able to locate accurate information regarding what the climate of a surfaced Zealandia have. For the purpose of the question, we will suppose that the continent gradually surfaced during the Pleistocene, before reaching the levels marked in this map at the beginning of the Holocene. Roughly a 2,000 meters lift.

The main objective is creative a continent where megafauna from all over the world (from the African Savanna to the Mammoth Steppe, with the Great Plains, the Pampas, etc) can be introduced in a somewhat stable manner. So would the climate and the ecosystems formed in this continent support this?

Without any information on the elevation of the various areas we can't give an answer, let alone a hard-science one

To put it another way, if you want a hard-science answer, then you need to ask a hard-science question - give us more information about atmospheric composition  at the time, some idea of latitude, some idea of oceanic currents including any thermocline flowing from the polar ice (if there is polar ice). It might be helpful to know a bit about the planet's orbit at the time - we may be able to help you construct a convincing scenario - we didn't have climate-measuring devices available at the time to give historically correct answers to this.

I think introducing that amount of mass to the globe has consequences of its own (as far as I can tell from a complete amateur's perspective). The Earth's orbit will probably change, and so will the moon's in return, changing global and local climate significantly.

Actually I withdraw the VTC, there is more than enough detail here to give a hard-science answer: No idea what the climate almost anywhere is going to be, two reasons:

This change creates a mountain ridge that blocks the Antarctic Circumpolar Current, south of Stewart Island and diverts gigatonnes of cold water north through the Tasman sea before forcing it to the surface off the Gold Coast.

If that wasn't enough of a disruption the new height of the Southern Alps puts them up in the southern hemispheres polar vortex diverting cold air north towards the Kermadec Islands and Coral Sea.


You've brought snow to subtropical Australia, killed the Great Barrier Reef and significantly cooled all of South East Asia; the global ramifications are, literally, incalculable.
